# How to create two separate sets of footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I would like to create a document with two different types of footnotes, ideally separated verticaly : one for critical aparatus (with a,b,c as footnote marks), and a second set for commentaries (with numbered footnote marks).

It would look a little like that : [image: Artscroll Hebrew Bible]

Comment: Will the layout be *always* like this? That is, you *always* have two sets of footnotes on *every* page? Or, could some pages have only one set of footnotes but not the other? Also, does the size of the footnote blocks differ, or are they fixed?

Comment: @Werner Ideally the two zones would not necessarly appear on every page and would not have a fixed dimension, but if there is no other way I could do with fixed zones.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found out that the Ledmac package can do this pretty easily.

Comment: Would you please add a simple example?

Comment: You should take a look on the successor package `eledmac`.